# Creating a span-12 split down the middle of the page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I'm working with rails 3 and haml as my view generator. Basically, I would like to be able to split the view in half with span-12's so that I can have two tables right next to each other. I figure there has to be simple way to do this with span tags.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Would doing this with css floating elements be more flexible for you? There is a tutorial that will walk you through takes you through multi-column layouts, floating drop-caps, images, and inline lists. You will find it here:

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

~Charles

Answer (score 0):

If I follow what you want (and I am assuming you are using bootstrap) then:

```
.row
  .span6
    .row
      %table
  .span6
    .row
      %table
```